# Unable to mock dynamoDBMapper.query

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Here is piece of code that i want to test

...

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Order> queryExpression = createQueryForLatestOrders(orderId, storeId, time);
PaginatedQueryList<Order> orders;
    try{
        orders = dynamoDBMapper.query(Order.class, queryExpression);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase){
        if (AmazonServiceException.ErrorType.Client.equals(ase.getErrorType())) {
            throw new InternalServiceException(ase);
        } else {
            throw new DependencyFailureException(ase);
        }
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
        throw new DependencyFailureException(e);
    }
  // other business logic
```

The function which is creating query is defined like this

```
private DynamoDBQueryExpression<Order> createQueryForLatestOrders(String orderId, String storeId, LocalDateTime time) { // ... implementation // }
```

...

and I a trying to test it like this

```
@Test(expected = DependencyFailureException.class)
public void testGetOrdersThrowsAWSServerException() throws Exception {
    when(mockDynamoDBMapper.scan(eq(Order.class), any())).thenThrow(AmazonServiceException.class);

    mockOrdersManager.getOrders(orderId, storeId, LocalDateTime.now());
}
```

But instead of being caught under `AmazonServiceException` the code moves on the next business logic. which makes me think that probably i am not doing mocking properly. What I am missing here.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the mock correctly? The code looks fine... The only thing I can think of is you may not be setting the mock in the object using the db mapper.

Comment: Aslo, I noted that you are mocking the .scan method... In your implementation you are using .query

Comment: sometimes, you know what you are doing is right but you forget that you haven't had caffeine in the longest time! and thats when you need a second eye ... replacing `scan` with `query` fixed the issue :) Please write your post as an answer so that i can accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine however I noted that you are mocking the .scan method... In your implementation you are using .query

I generally use jmockit, in jmockit doing this would result in an empty object being returned I think in mokito it would end up returning null. If this is true, an NPE will be thrown and your test will continue due to the wrong exception being caught.